# Ask for username at sign up but not allow users to sign In with it (only email)

Tags: meteor

When users sign up in my app (with accounts-ui) I ask for three mandatory fields: username, email and pwd. I'm looking for a way to allow users to sign In with only two fields: Email and password (not username/email and pwd as default) but always asking for username in sign up (Usernames could be duplicates between users).

There is a way to do that with accounts-ui?  The reason is pretty obvious, as facebook do, I need to allow the creation of different accounts with the same name, but not with the same email.

As workaround I have installed a package to add the additional field to sign Up (selaias:accounts-entry) and customize the sign in / sign up forms but the additional field (username) is shown below the password which looks awkward.  I wonder if meteor accounts should have a natural option to do the explained at begin.

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1

Pass `passwordSignupFields:'EMAIL_ONLY'` to [Accounts.ui.config](http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Accounts-ui-config)

### Option 2

Part 1: Pass a custom validation method to [Accounts.validateNewUser](https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#requiring-username-email) so duplicate usernames are allowed.

Part 2:

> the additional field (username) is shown below the password which looks awkward.

Hide it with a CSS hack

Comment: Actually, I need the field username in my app, so that's why I ask for it in sign up.  The issue is that I don't want to allow users to later sign in using username, just email.

Comment: Then maybe option 2

Comment: The Accounts.validateNewUser runs in client, but in my case the server is which rejects the duplicate username when calling Accounts.createUser